# Find the intersection points between [0, 2pi] interval.

Tags: trigonometry

I have troubles finding the $x$ intersection points of the following function   $f(x)=2 \sin(x)-1$ between the [0, 2pi] interval. How would I proceed to solve such a problem?

I tried $0=2 \sin(x)-1$ but I doubt this is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're called intercepts. Solve $0= 2 \sin(x) -1$ for one $x$, then use periodicity of $\sin(x)$ to note that in an interval of length $2 \pi$, theres exactly 2 solutions to this equation.

Comment: Ended up following this solution [link](http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Trigonometry-basics/Trigonometry-basics.faq.question.443733.html) that guided me on the right path. Thank you very much for your help!